# Why I cannot display available milestones in new issue form inside Chrome (cypress)?

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I'm writing a test that uses github to create sample issue with a milestone.

When I'm manually testing it in Chrome, I'm seeing available milestone:

[image]

However, when I run test in Cypress environment, I see:

[image]

I'm clicking on a Milestone section header (sidebar):

```
cy.get('.sidebar-milestone > .js-issue-sidebar-form > .details-reset > .text-bold').click()
```

I've noticed a log message in cypress browser:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource
>   'https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-ed9a6ebff11490e3b6a311cb47b71cae.js'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   'iFmDof4l/ZHJ+J0GQf5D37I57MPxzmTIxA1gE35EH2g='. The resource has been
>   blocked.

I didn't notice any errors during manual testing (standalone running chrome)

For manual and e2e (cypress) testing I'm using the same browser: Chrome 68 (OSX).

Full test case code:

```
describe('Test whether kanban board working', function() {
  it('Visits the board', function() {

    cy.visit('https://github.com/login')
    cy.get('#login_field').type('ACCOUNT_NAME')
    cy.get('#password').type('PASSWORD')
    cy.get('.btn').click()

    cy.request({
      url: 'https://github.com/ACCOUNT_NAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/issues/new',
    })
    .then((resp) => {
      // redirect status code is 302
      expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
    })

    cy.visit('https://github.com/ACCOUNT_NAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/issues/new')
    cy.get('#issue_title').type('New issue ' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1))
    cy.get('.sidebar-milestone > .js-issue-sidebar-form > .details-reset > .text-bold').click()
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you share a "working" (I mean everything needed to go straight to the error) repo/gist to reproduce it and focusing on debugging it?

Comment: @NoriSte question updated. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes I can reproduce the problem. It's something related to the mouse management because as soon as you enter the GitHub window (when the Cypress script is stuck) everything starts to work. I don't think and I'll come up with a solution but I can create a repo to submit as a PR to Cypress (I tested with TestCafé and it works, tomorrow I'll test with Puppeteer)

Answer (score 2):

Here I am with a repository where I compared Cypress with Puppeteer and TestCafè because the behavior seems really strange...

I think that the issue is related to some strange mouse management of Cypress because on Puppeteer and TestCafè everything works fine.

See [the repository](https://github.com/NoriSte/stackoverflow-52383438-cypress-issue)
And the screenshot that compares them

[image: comparison]

[EDIT]

Then I tried to log every mouse events happening in page, the result is the following

TestCafè

> mouseover ... mousemove ... mousemove ...
>   mousedown ... mouseup ... click ...

Puppeteer

> mouseover ​…​​ mousemove
>   ​…​​ mousedown
>   ​…​​ mouseup ​…​​ click ​…​​

Cypress

> mousedown ... mouseup ... click

(see the complete log on my [repo page](https://github.com/NoriSte/stackoverflow-52383438-cypress-issue))

As you can see there aren't mousemove events at all...

I found some issue opened that could be related... I'll create a dedicated (and simpler) repo before submitting them an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work, I'll test it again in the weekend.

Comment: I then created a simpler repo to show the Cypress team the issue
https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-mousemove-issue

Comment: At the moment I can't get the test work even with some artificial events ( cy.trigger('mousemove', { pageX: 600, pageY: 600 }) ) trying to replicate the real mouse behavior... (I tried triggering the event on the body, on the textarea or on the element the GitHub's script is listening to)

Comment: @drupality they're working on that issue 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2521

Comment: @drupality, they've released it 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2521#issuecomment-545651054